# I want a constant background red colored button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: This is my button code in an expanded widget i want the button to be constantly red like it was on FlatButton(), I want a constant background red colored button using TextButton in flutter. And the background color should fill the entire expanded section.]

```
Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
          primary: Colors.red,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        child: const Text("False"),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
```

[![I want the Red color in background to be constantly filled !! the buttons are now filling when they are hovered ][2]][2]

Comment: The picture you posted, is that the desired outcome, or is that something you have achieved so far? If you haven't already, please post the desired outcome.

Comment: its the one i achieved

Comment: please post the desired outcome

Comment: desired outcome is a solid background button with a text on it

Comment: how about elvatedButton on this case

Comment: does the elevated button will work ?

Comment: can't i just change the padding in TextButton

Comment: I have updated the required one @WSBT

Comment: @Kushal_Hemanth Yeah, that's just a normal `ElevatedButton` to me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by just simply using the ElevatedButton instead of TextButton and here how it goes :-) Thanks for your answers and guidence:

```
Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
          primary: Colors.red,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        child: const Text("False"),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, use `backgroundColor`, also I will prefer `ElevatedButton`

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          child: TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
              primary: Colors.red,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "False",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              primary: Colors.red,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "False",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method which is using the Container wrapped with InkWell (if you want to have respond when touched)

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 10),
      child: const Text("False"),
    ),
  ),
));
```

[image: This is the output]